# Close mootools Rokbox through Javascript

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am using the mootools based Rokbox plugin, on one of my sites, and I can't figure out how to close it with javascript.

I triggered the click event on the close button, but that did not work.

I found the code in the rokbox source that is used to add the click listener

```
this.closeButton.addEvent('click',function(e){new Event(e).stop();self.swtch=false;self.close(e)});
```

but since it is minified i cannot find what "this" refers to

Answer (score 1):

The `this` likely refers to the rokbox instance; I don't think you need to worry about it, you're interested in the code that runs on the click event. The salient part looks to be the following:

```
self.swtch=false;
self.close(e);
```

`self` most likely refers to the rokbox instance, again, so assuming you instantiate it with something like

```
var rokbox = new RokBox(...);
```

you should be able to just call

```
rokbox.close();
```

and have it close. I haven't looked at rokbox source, so no guarantees, and not quite sure what the `swtch=false` does, so you probably will need to experiment a bit.

Answer (score 0):

For the current rokbox and mootools 1.12, the command is

```
window.parent.rokbox.close(null)
```

it took forever to come up with this. By the way, this is to close the rokbox from the page that's loaded in the rokbox, by clicking a regular button instead of the 'x' for instance. Also, to add to what Aeon wrote, the rokbox is automatically created so it's unnecessary to instantiate it.

Comment: unfortunately, I've now discovered this doesn't work in the administrator backend, because the rokbox-config does a "var rokbox = new RokBox({" wheres in the front end, it's "rokbox = new RokBox({" without the 'var' so that rokbox has global scope.